# How do I obtain IPv4 subnet prefix/mask in Android WITHOUT root?

Tags: java, android, networking, subnet

I can't use DhcpInfo (it's deprecated) and I've tried using InterfaceAddress.getNetworkPrefixLength. getNetworkPrefixLength returns a /64 (which is impossible for an IPv4 address) even when I am passing an Inet4Address. The Android documentation instructs me to use LinkProperties but I can't find any documentation.

EDIT:
I can't rely on a rooted phone

EDIT#2: System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true"); doesn't work according to [Dianne Hackborne](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/LXW9jGN6QkU/e9Ew5ovmmY0J)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get ip adress, ip netmask,... of an android device is using the android terminal emulator. It's a terminal based in linux and if you type there:

```
ifconfig
```

ifconfig is a program that tells you the specifications of an interface (of an android device).

Here's some info about ifconfig:

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ifconfig8.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will I need root? Is the output of Androids implementation of ifconfig consistent across all devices and APIs?

Comment: Yes, to execute ifconfig you have to be root. About second question, I've never tried, but the output should be allways consistent across all android devices (different versions of Android)

Comment: It was informative but it doesn't solve my problem. Approximately 1% of Android users have rooted phones and I'm not catering to that user base.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Kotlin code for getting the ipv4 address and its mask. The trick is that if you convert an InterfaceAddress to a String you get a string that contains an IP address, the mask and the IP broadcast address. You then use a RegEx to extract the IP and the mask from that string. The InterfaceAddress for IPv4 address internally contains the mask, but doesn't expose it directly. So this is a technique that you can use to get the mask without using reflection. Obviously there's no guarantee that this code won't break if the InterfaceAddress.toString() is changed in some future release.

```
 var ifAddr: InterfaceAddress? = getInterfaceAddress()
 println ("ip: " + getIPAddr(ifAddr!!) + " mask: " + getIPMask(ifAddr))



fun getInterfaceAddress(): InterfaceAddress?
{
    try
    {
         //Enumerate all the network interfaces
        var en:Enumeration<NetworkInterface> = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
        while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
            var intf: NetworkInterface = en.nextElement();
            // Make a loop on the number of IP addresses related to each Network Interface
            var interfaceAddresses: MutableList<InterfaceAddress> = intf.interfaceAddresses
            for (i in 0 until interfaceAddresses.size) {
                var ifAddr = interfaceAddresses.get(i)
                if (ifAddr.toString().indexOf((":")) < 0) {
                    println(ifAddr)
                    if (!ifAddr.address.isLoopbackAddress)
                        return ifAddr
                }

            }

        }
    } catch (e: SocketException)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

fun getIPAddr(ifAddr: InterfaceAddress): String {
    var pattern = Regex("/([0-9,.]*)/")
    val result = pattern.find(ifAddr.toString())
    if (result != null) {
        var g = result.groupValues
        if (g.size > 1) return g.get(1)
    }
    return ""
}

fun getIPMask(ifAddr: InterfaceAddress): Int {
    var pattern = Regex(".*/([0-9]*)\\s")
    val result = pattern.find(ifAddr.toString())
    if (result != null) {
        var g = result.groupValues
        if (g.size > 1) return g.get(1).toInt()
    }
    return 0
}
```